# Node Transversal with gremlin with group clause

Tags: graph-databases, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

Can anyone  help with graph transverse using gremlin .I have connected graph data  were i need to query user contact with relationship 'KNOWS'
and its outgoing connection vertices properties .

```
g.addV().property(id, 'user').as('user').
addV().property(id, 'user1').as('user1').
addV().property(id, 'user2').as('user2').
addV().property(id, 'user3').as('user3').
addV().property(id, 'user4').as('user4').
addV().property(id, 'Industry1').as('Industry1').
addV().property(id, 'Industry2').as('Industry2').
addV().property(id, 'skills1').as('skills1').
addV().property(id, 'skills2').as('skills2').    
addE('KNOWS').from('user').to('user1').
addE('KNOWS').from('user').to('user2').
addE('KNOWS').from('user').to('user3').
addE('KNOWS').from('user').to('user4').
addE('WORKS').from('user1').to('Industry1').
addE('WORKS').from('user2').to('Industry1').
addE('WORKS').from('user2').to('Industry2').
addE('WORKS').from('user3').to('Industry2').
addE('SKILLEDIN').from('user3').to('skills1').
addE('SKILLEDIN').from('user4').to('skills1').
addE('SKILLEDIN').from('user4').to('skills2')
```

What is required- navigating from user node get all outgoing connection with relationship 'KNOWS' and for each connection get his industry and skills 
The output should be traversal result from user

user1---Industry1,skills1
user2--Industry1,Industry2
user3--Industry3,skills1
user4--skills1,skills2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the output you want:

```
gremlin> g.V('user').out('KNOWS').
......1>   group().
......2>     by(id).
......3>     by(project('industries','skills').
......4>          by(out('WORKS').id().fold()).
......5>          by(out('SKILLEDIN').id().fold()))
==>[user1:[industries:[Industry1],skills:[]],user2:[industries:[Industry1,Industry2],skills:[]],user3:[industries:[Industry2],skills:[skills1]],user4:[industries:[],skills:[skills1,skills2]]]
```

Comment: Thanks you stephen for your quick response , I have run this query against the data and could not find a way to get name property instead of node Id  "a3aecb62-5a78-45ed-92b1-f582d6c6b3da": {
      "industries": [],
      "skills": [
        "d1fd2604-eff3-e711-8153-e0071b670e51",
        "99473fef-8d66-e711-818a-f0921c124e44"
      ]

Comment: you can see where i used `id` or `id()` - just replace with '"name"' and `values("name")` respectively. that should do it.

Comment: Thank you very much stephen .This solves the problem . Just for clarification what if i need to grab any additional custom properties from the transversed node . Like user2 firstname or industry account no. Is this solution can be extended to give me custom value

Comment: Gremlin gives you all the tools you need to do that. It sounds like you need to look at more documentation for how you transform data to the form that you want. for example,  if you want more than industry name, then rather than `values("name")` you should probably `valueMap('name','accountNumber')`.